# Refeshing a page to a new state

Tags: php, cookies, session-state

I have a written a [blog](http://dev.haaga.org/~macy/Blog/index.php) using php and mysql which has a login feature. When you are logged out and hit back it should not show the features of a member since you are no longer logged in. How do I correct it so that when a user is no longer logged in and hit back button, the previous page should be in the state before he logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to discern what authentication mechanism you're using, but assuming this is a pure caching issue you can add the following statements to the beginning of all .php pages displayed while logged in.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1970 05:00:00 GMT");
```

That should take care of caching issues. And make sure that you `unset()` the access variable you used to keep track of wether or not the user is logged in (in `$_SESSION` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser feature. But don't worry, you won't be able to actually do any admin-level stuff if you're not *actually* logged in. If you wanted, you could fire off a request to the server via javascript to ask if the user is logged in upon loading a page. If that request comes back false, you can hide the admin controls, or redirect the user to the index page.

You could explicitly state in code that you wish to *not cache* the pages, but that will slow down visitor-experience, and cause more overhead for your server. I don't think the ends justify the means in that particular solution.